# Как получить значение выделенного текста?

Tags: javascript

```
<p class="text">One Two Three Four Five</p>
```

Как получить значение текста при клике\при выделении на конкретное слово? Т.е. нажму на `Four` - получу значение `Four`, а не все пять слов в блоке.

```
var textNode = document.querySelector(".text");

    textNode.onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.innerHTML);
    }
```

Как сделать так, чтобы получать значение только конкретного слова?
Так тоже не работает:)

```
textNode.onclick = function(e) {
            console.log(e.innerHTML);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое использовать метод `window.getSelection()`. Если выделить на странице текст и выполнить код ниже в консоли браузера, то результатом вывода будет выделенный текст. К сожалению в песочнице `SO` этот код не работает.

```
console.log( window.getSelection( ).toString( ) );
```

Материалы для изучения - [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Selection), [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Range).